# Am I missing something in my function?

Tags: c++, string, function, reverse

This is what I have so far and I keep getting an error. Any help?

```
void ReverseString(char* string) {
    int len = strlen(string);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
         string[i] = string[len-i];
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know the error. Is it because you're using `{` at the end of the `for` block?

Comment: I think you're missing `std::string` and `std::reverse`, myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- When `i` is `0` you'll be accessing
  `string[len]` which is incorrect as
  the valid index in an array of length
  `len` are `[0,len-1]`

If I understand you intent correctly you are trying to reverse the string but I can see a few things missing:

- You are not swapping.
- Also the swapping should happen for
  one half of the array, not for the
  entire array.

The following snippet fixes these issues:

```
int len = strlen(string);
for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
    swap(string[len-i-1],string[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you would get an error on line 6.

Change the `{` into `}`. Then try again.

Comment: Thats a copy error on my part. Thats not why Im getting the error however.

Comment: @Josh Lake You accepted an answer so I guess the problem is solved and there is no need for me to change mine.

Answer (score 1):

Besides two already mentioned errors:

You'll make a palindrom out of the original string. The first half will became equal to second half inversed. However, the second half will remain the same. This is not what the function name declares.

Answer (score 1):

This is tagged C++, do it the C++ way...

```
std::string ReverseString(std::string str) 
{
  std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
  return str;
}
```

Comment: how about `return std::string(str.rbegin(), str.rend());` Then you can even take the input as const reference.

Answer (score 0):

should be `string[i] = string[len-i-1];`

```
// added (untested):  

void ReverseString(char * string) {   
    int len = strlen(string);  
    for(int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)  
    {  
         string[i] ^= string[len-i-1];  
         string[len-i-1] ^= string[i];  
         string[i] ^= string[len-i-1];  
    }  
}
```

Comment: oops, reversing string in place requires swaps, my bad